# Fix strange highlight behavior in Spyder IDE

Tags: python, spyder

This definitely qualifies as a stupid question. Why does Spyder IDE seemingly randomly highlight different functions or logic blocks? I find this very distracting and it makes writing code more difficult. Im sure it's something I'm doing wrong as I'm quite new to python (From R) but please help if you can.

[Example of behavior on while loop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4kKQL.png)

[Example of behavior on function blocks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OF1kY.png)

I am using Spyder 5.4.5. I am using the base Spyder py env. I have tried different tricks to un-highlight the code like shift+tabbing the code out of the function/logic block and tabbing it back, adding blank lines between the function creation line, ctrl+x then ctrl+v the function/code block, etc.. I know I am running an older version of Spyder so that could be the issue but it could also be a UI setting that I need to adjust.

Thank you!

Comment: I'm using 5.4.3 at the moment and if you put the insertion point in a word or identifer Spyder highlights other occurrences of the same word elsewhere in the document, but I don't see any 'random' highlighting of blocks of text as your images show. Can you describe a reproducible procedure that produces this highlighting, starting from a new Spyder document?